# another policeman has been injured as fighting continued this morning

Tags: sentence-structure

> another policeman has been injured as fighting continued this morning

Is the above sentence correct because I think that it should have been written that as:

> another policeman has been injured as fighting **has continued** since this morning.

*Has been injured* means injury took place now but fighting continued this morning means it was in continuation this morning – not now – and we are using as for comparison, so both the events should be contemporary in order to use *as*.

Comment: What makes you think it's incorrect?

Comment: You might find [ell.se] to be a good home for future questions.

Comment: In this case, _as_ is not used to compare anything. It simply means that something happened _while_ something else was happening. _I listened to the radio as I was making tea_. That means they happen at the same time, not that I listened in the same way that I made tea.

Comment: Someone somewhere has misled you about how the simple past and the present perfect work or do not work.

Comment: "*Has been injured* means injury took place now" - no, it means that the injury took place some time before now.

Answer (score 1):

Both may be correct.  As oerkelens' comment mentions, "as" is commonly used to start an adverbial phrase which describes the time frame of the action in the sentence.  Some examples:

> I **listened** to the radio as I **was making** tea.

The main action is in the past, but from the perspective of that moment, the tea-making is continuous.  Similarly, with a present action:

> The fighting **continues** as the rebel forces **are moving** closer to the capitol.

Depending on the reporter's perspective, any of the following are fine:

> The fighting **has continued** as the rebel forces **move** closer to the capitol.
>
> The fighting **continued** as the rebel forces **moved** closer to the capitol.
>
> The fighting **had continued** as the rebel forces **were moving** closer to the capitol.

As well as other combinations. The only rule is that the tenses have to make sense in context.  For example, it's a little strange to say that something *is happening* as something else *happened*:

> The fighting **continues** as the rebel forces **moved** closer to the capitol.

However, this may not be entirely wrong, since "as" can also imply *causation* (similar to the word "since"), and not just *simultaneity*.

> Wait a few minutes before drinking your tea, **as** it is may be very hot when first poured.

Answer (score 0):

The first sentence is correct.

It would also be correct to write

**Another policeman was injured as fighting continued this morning.**

In this case with 2 verbs in the simple past you are emphasising 1) the injury took place in the past 2) the morning is over, i.e. also in the past.

But if you wish to emphasise that the injury is ongoing you can use the present perfect in the main clause -- *the present perfect is used for a result that is valid in the present*. If, in addition, the time is also over, then you can use the simple past in the subordinate clause. This corresponds to your first (correct) sentence.

> **Another policeman has been injured as fighting continued this morning**.

If it *still* is morning, you would use the present tense for the main clause and write:

**Another policeman has been injured as fighting *continues* this morning.**

---

Incidentally your second sentence could also be grammatically correct, but it would have a *different meansing*. 'As' would not mean 'while', but '**because**'.
The morning is not over; the injury is has a result in the present. So you can write:

**Another policeman has been injured because/as fighting has continued this morning.**